# How do I add a picture from the camera to an ImageView in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, camera, imageview

My Java class code has a Button that lets the user access the camera, take a picture, and then that picture is to be added to an ImageView.
I have failed to achieve this functionality.

Here is my  java code:

```
package com.example.vikingpianomovers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class QuoteFormActivity extends Activity {


String mCurrentPhotoPath;
protected static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1111;
protected static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = null;
private static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 0;
ImageView mImageView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_form);


    final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    final EditText emailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
    final EditText phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditPhoneNumber);
    final EditText makeModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextMakeModel);
    final EditText pianoSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPianoSize);
    final Spinner measurementUnit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    final EditText cityOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextCityOrigin);
    final EditText cityDest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextCityDest);
    final EditText stairs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextStairs);
    final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attachedImage1);
    final ImageView mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attachedImage2);

    //button that starts the camera
    Button addPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.attachPicButton);
    addPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //button click invokes method to start camera
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }

    });

    //button that sends data from form to user's email
    Button email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
    email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //intent to send email

            Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            email.setType("plain/text");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"vikingpianomovers@yahoo.com"});
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Viking Android App Submission");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                    "name: " + name.getText().toString() + '\n' + '\n' +
                    "Email Address: " + emailAddress.getText().toString()+ '\n' + '\n' +
                    "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber.getText().toString() + '\n' + '\n' +
                    "Make and Model: " + makeModel.getText().toString() + '\n' + '\n' +
                    "Piano Size: " + pianoSize.getText().toString()+ '\n' + '\n' +
                    "City of Origin: " + cityOrigin.getText().toString() + '\n' + '\n' +
                    "City Destination: " + cityDest.getText().toString() + '\n' + '\n' +
                    "Number of stairs: " + stairs.getText().toString() + '\n' + '\n' +
                    "Pic(s): " + mImageView
                    );
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
        }
    });

    //layout params for LinearLayout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    //Create a new LinearLayout
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

@Override
//result of dispatchTakePictureIntent
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}

//method to create image file in external directory
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0));
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

//method containing intent to access camera and create image file
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
           Log.i("photoFile not created", mCurrentPhotoPath);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

public QuoteFormActivity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/vikingmobilequotelogo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/namehint"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/emailhint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/phonenumberhint"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/piano_type"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="10dp">
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextMakeModel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/piano_make_model_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditTextPianoSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/piano_size_hint"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp">
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:entries="@array/piano_measurement_type"
    android:prompt="@string/piano_type_prompt" >
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditTextCityOrigin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/origin_hint"
    android:padding="10dp">
</EditText>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditTextCityDest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/dest_hint"
    android:padding="10dp">
</EditText>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditTextStairs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/stairs_hint"
    android:padding="10dp">
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewSubmit"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/submit_text"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attachPicButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/picButton" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/attachedImage1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >"
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/attachedImage2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit_button_text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
</Button>
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vikingpianomovers"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/viking_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="QuoteFormActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: sir have you searched stackoverflow for your question?

Comment: Yes, painstakingly.  Since I haven't been able to figure this out after all the searching I figured I would post my code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@Override
//result of dispatchTakePictureIntent
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(new BitmapDrawable(getBaseContext(),
                        getPath(data.getData(),getBaseContext())));
     }
}
```

add this method too

```
public String getPath(Uri uri,Context c) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = c.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) 
        return null;
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return s;
}
```

Sir, This question and answer is a duplicate of soo many questions on stackoverflow, i do not know for you, but if you are okay with it, then after this answer solves your problem do not accept it and delete the question, so to help clean the site,after all your problem has been solved